# function should return the output while the process works in a separate go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"

    er "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    errorsChan := make(chan error) // remove the length and see the error happens!

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            say(5)

            errorsChan <- er.Wrap(errors.New("first one"), "first test")
        }()

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            say(1)

            errorsChan <- er.Wrap(errors.New("something"), "another test")
        }()
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(errorsChan)
    }()

    for item := range errorsChan {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }

    // time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    fmt.Print("HELLO\n")
}

func say(i time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(i * time.Second)
}
```

I want to print `HELLO` first before the error messages.

Right now `HELLO` is waiting for the above error messages, and then gets printed.
and if I remove the top level `wg.Add(1)` then I am getting the error `panic: send on closed channel`

What is the change that I should make?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of reading through the code, i found the solution.

i should put the `wg.Wait()` and `close(errorsChan)` code inside the top level go routine. Since it is were the `errorsChan` is needed, and the printing `HELLO` can be on the main go routine.

so the corrected answer will be like below:

```
 package main
    
    import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "time"
    
        er "github.com/pkg/errors"
    )
    
    func main() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        errorsChan := make(chan error) // remove the length and see the error happens!
    
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
    
                say(5)
    
                errorsChan <- er.Wrap(errors.New("first one"), "first test")
            }()
    
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
    
                say(1)
    
                errorsChan <- er.Wrap(errors.New("something"), "another test")
            }()

go func() {
            wg.Wait()
            close(errorsChan)
        }()
    
        for item := range errorsChan {
            fmt.Println(item)
        }
        }()
    
        
    
        // time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
        fmt.Print("HELLO\n")
    }
    
    func say(i time.Duration) {
        time.Sleep(i * time.Second)
    }
```